# What package do I need to build a Qt 5 & CMake application?

Tags: package-management, qt, qt5, cmake

I'm trying to build [sdrangelove](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/sdrangelove), which wants Qt 5 and uses CMake for its build system, on Ubuntu 13.10. What package do I need to install to give it the file it's asking for here?

There are a lot of `*qt5*` packages, and I've tried installing the promising looking ones to no effect. All the discussions I've found either have things working fine or are talking about writing CMake build rules rather than executing them. I don't have a lot of experience with the organization of Debian/Ubuntu packaging.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core"
  (requested version 5.0) with any of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two things I was missing:

- After an unsuccessful build, I must remove `CMakeCache.txt` (or simply clear the build directory); otherwise `cmake` will report the same error even if the needed package has been installed.
- The packages which provide the `*.cmake` configuration files have names of the form `qt*5-dev`, e.g. for the error in my question, `qtcore5-dev`.

Comment: Another option is to use apt-file to search the missing package:

`apt-file search Qt5CoreConfig.cmake

qtbase5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake

qtbase5-gles-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
`

Comment: @FranciscoV. What you have written deserves to be in an answer. It'll be easier to read the example that way, too.

Answer (score 70):

I just stumbled upon this question while trying to compile [KeePassX 2.0](https://www.keepassx.org/news/2015/12/533).

What helped me was to use [apt-file](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptFile) to search for the missing packages:

For example running this:

> apt-file search Qt5CoreConfig.cmake

Returned the following packages:

> qtbase5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
>
> qtbase5-gles-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake

These packages can then be installed with apt or apt-get, e.g.:

> sudo apt install qtbase5-dev

Comment: quick ref for apt-file (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptFile). works.

Comment: first time that I see this tool. It's very... very, very useful! :-)

Comment: Thanks! I was totally missing these files by grepping for strings including "qt5".

Answer (score 4):

If you tried the above solutions and it didn't work, also try `apt-get install libqt5opengl5-dev`, that worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Also, possible to fix the installation issue, by direct package install through rpm (See the content https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/phonon-qt5-devel-4.8.3-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).

And another possibility is through "source build and install" : http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.9/kde/phonon.html

*This is typically due to improper installation of the phonon4qt5 (version 4.8.3) through "apt-get". At times, this is resolvable by "synaptic" installs for the missing libs/parts of the package.*