# Ubuntu 14.04 Qt5 development libraries?

Tags: 14.04, cmake, qt5

I want to build applications requiring Qt5 via CMake.

Which libraries do I have to install to achieve that?

What I have tried so far is searching for anything containing qt 5 core and dev, but have turned up empty:

```
apt-cache search qt | grep dev | grep core
```

only returns

```
libtulip-dev - Tulip graph library - core development files
```

The only thing seeming half-way to fit is "libqt5core5a", but installing that doesn't provide any development libraries...

Do I need any additional repositories? The ones from Kubuntu maybe?

Searching the web didn't yet give me any proper answers too (probably not the right keywords, I know, but :o). I e.g. found this question: [What package do I need to build a Qt 5 & CMake application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374755/what-package-do-i-need-to-build-a-qt-5-cmake-application), but there is no qtcore5-dev package in trusty repositories it seems...

Edit: Upon further experimenting, I did have qmake installed, but the 4.8.6 version (qt4-qmake). Trying to install the 5.x version brought no joy, though - (`sudo apt-get purge qt4-qmake && sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake`) - qmake now reports:

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

Is there something broken in the repositories here?

Comment: Related or even duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/508503/20275

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems

```
> apt-file search Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
```

was what I was missing. This got me

```
qtbase5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
```

Installing that seems to lead to CMake finding Qt5. qmake still reports the same problem when directly called though...some remnant from qt4 still installed it seems...

Edit: As for the qmake problem, this is fixed by

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Comment: Didn't knew of apt-flie, very useful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

1) Where is your qtchooser configuration file?

$: locate qtchooser | grep conf

2) From the list of conf files, probably there is one call "default.conf"
  This one is a link to one of the others (4.conf or qt4.conf or 5.conf or qt5.conf).
  Choose the one that makes sense too you, and create a link to it.

Suppose your default file path is

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf

Create backup:
  $: cd $(dirname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf)
  $: cp -av default.conf default.conf_backup

Let's say you target is 
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf

Then:
  $: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf default.conf

3) Is the path to your qmake right?

Check qmake location
  $: locate qmake | grep bin

Is the same one as indicated in your modified qtchooser/default.conf?
  $: cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf

If the answer is YES, then you are done.
  If the anser is no, then you need to modify the file:

Create backup:

```
  $: cd $(dirname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf)
  $: cp -av qt5.conf qt5.conf_backup
```

Edit file and change path to your qmake location

```
  $ sudo vi qt5.conf
```

Now it is done.