# Install dnscrypt-proxy-gui

Tags: software-installation, dnscrypt-proxy

What I've tried so far:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/F1ash/dnscrypt-proxy-gui
```

And I think it only downloaded the source code (?).

I also tried `make` but it doens't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install `cmake`:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Or install the latest version of `cmake` by visiting [cmake.org](https://cmake.org/download/) and downloading the latest source distribution.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
tar -xf cmake-3.10.2.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.10.2
./configure
make
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

And you need these to be able to compile DNSCrypt-Proxy-GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install extra-cmake-modules
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
sudo apt-get install libkf5auth-dev
sudo apt-get install libkf5notifications-dev
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-private-dev
```

Download the latest DNSCrypt-Proxy-GUI from [here](https://github.com/F1ash/dnscrypt-proxy-gui/releases)

```
tar -xf  dnscrypt-proxy-gui-1.11.11.tar.gz
cd dnscrypt-proxy-gui-1.11.11
sudo cmake ./
sudo checkinstall
```

Now run DNSCrypt-Proxy-GUI with:

```
DNSCryptClient
```

Helpful links:

[How to install cmake 3.2 on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu)

https://github.com/psifidotos/Latte-Dock/issues/485

[What package do I need to build a Qt 5 & CMake application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374755/what-package-do-i-need-to-build-a-qt-5-cmake-application)